# Does the damage from the drawback of wish prevent the casting of the triggering spell if the damage kills the caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

> **Wish** [...] After enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage per level of that spell.

If this damage kills you, will the spell that caused the necrotic damage still happen or are you reduced to 0 HP before the spell effect occurs, thereby stopping it?

Answer (score 14):

## The spell will be cast

Wish says:

> each time you cast a spell

it does not say "each time you *attempt* to cast" or anything similar. When a spell is cast, it is complete and its effects will take place.<sup>1</sup>

## ...but maybe not for long

If the caster dies from this damage, the effect on the spell will depend on which spell was cast.

Obviously any spell with a concentration requirement will cease to work. Anything that interacts with the spellcaster dying/dropping to 0hp/taking damage may take place depending on the wording.

However, a spell with a duration of instantaneous will take effect immediately (before the damage/death).

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless some specific rule like the ready action supersedes this.

Comment: I suggest wishing for a Clone ;-)